# Как создать рекурсивный Promise?

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь понять каким образом дождаться выполнение промиса, если по условию нужно опять вызвать его:

```
 const promise = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const random = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
  if(random === 1) {
    console.log('YES')
     resolve(true);
  } else {
    console.log('wait...')
     promise();
  }
})

const startPromise = async () => { 
   const result = await promise(); //Если результат не приходит с первого раза, то код ниже не выполняется
    if(result) {
      console.log('done')
    }
}
```

Как дождаться пока промис вернет результат, если `int  != 1` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот, позапускайте несколько раз, будет разное количество ожиданий в консоли:

```js
const promise = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
    if(random === 1) {
        console.log('YES')
        resolve(true);
    } else {
        console.log('wait...')
        // Здесь дожидаемся. Без этого будет оборванная цепочка действий
        // (действий будет несколько, но конец завершения ошибочный (преждевременный))
        // или вовсе конца не будет
        promise().then(resolve).catch(reject);
    }
});

const startPromise = async () => {
    const result = await promise(); //Если результат не приходит с первого раза, то код ниже не выполняется
    if(result) {
        console.log('done')
    }
}

startPromise();
```

Answer (score 0):

Честно говоря, ничего не понятно. В `promise` `data` это что такое? Если бросать число в `startPromise` то оно никогда не изменится и `promise` ваш будет или вечно крутится или сразу разрешится если вы ему единичку прокинете туда.

Сделал как понял. Если что-то не так - пишите уточнение.

```js
const promise = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const random = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
  console.log('Promise', random);
  if(random === 1) {
     resolve(true);
  } else {
     promise();
  }
})

const startPromise = async () => await promise();

startPromise();
```

Comment: Да, извиняюсь, ошибся что число не в промисе генерировал. 
Суть в том, что почему-то если рандомное число не с первого раза = 1, то дальше await promise() код не выполняется

Comment: поменял код в вопросе на ваш и дополнил, чтоб была ясность